# mark long lines in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

In some editors, overlong lines are marked. e.g. by a vertical bar after column 80, or by shading everything after column 80.

Can I do this in eclipse?

Answer (score 27):

eclipse: Window > Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors: show print margin [checkbox] And: print margin column [...]

Answer (score 0):

You could use the checkstyle plugin [Download site here](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/downloads.html)

Comment: Doh. Preferences, Text-Editors, Checkbox: "Show print margin".

Comment: Ah :) didn't realise that's all you wanted. Still, take a look at checkstyle for your needs. It highlights lines that have issues, and you can use the quick fix option to solve some of the more common issues.